# Make a custom date from variable

Tags: php, date

I am using PHP and have a variable number which will be dynamic and I want to create a date on its behalf.

```
$number = 4;
```

I can create the date after one day by

`echo date('c', strtotime('+1 day'));`

what if i want to create a date after certain number of days i.e `$number` of days.

How can I create the date in the behalf of `$number`.

Comment: What is "on behalf"? This question is unclear: what does the number mean and what do you want to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you properly then you can just do something like this:

```
$number = 4;
$days = "+".$number." day";
echo date('c', strtotime($days));
```

if this is not what you want to do then please clarify your question